# Using glob import causes reference error in preact vite

Tags: typescript, vite, preact

I am trying to use the glob import from vite to subsitute my require.context that I used to use when back when I still used webpack and react. The exact error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $RefreshReg$ is not defined at base-app-config.tsx:2:33
```

I get this error whenever I try to load up the page using pnpm run dev

Well I tried to search on google for some concrete answers to as why it's not working. And I couldn't come up with any good answers or any answers that solved my issue.

My file where I am glob importing using vite:

```
const components = {};

// const requireComponent = require.context(
//     '../../main', // components folder
//     true, // look subfolders
//     /_config\.tsx$/, //regex for files
// )

export function getConfigObject() {
    const modules = import.meta.glob('../../main/**/_config.tsx');

    // requireComponent.keys().forEach(filePath => {
    //     const component = requireComponent(filePath);
    //     components[filePath] = component;
    // });

    for (const path in modules) {
        modules[path]().then((mod) => {
            components[path] = mod;
        });
    }

    return components;
}
```

The commented out part is my old code that I used for webpack/react.

The error occurs when I try to import the getConfigObject in one of my other files (base-app-config.tsx)

Here is that file:

```
import { Component, FunctionComponent } from "preact";
import { getConfigObject } from "./lib/config/config";

export async function GetAppConfig(): Promise<any> {
    const configs = await getConfigObject();
    const uiApps = Object.keys(getConfigObject());

    uiApps.forEach((config) => {
        if (typeof configs[config].default === "function") {
            const data = configs[config].default();
            uiApps.push(data);
        }
    });

    return (
        uiApps
    );
}
```

P.s also I am using vite-plugin-javascript-obfuscator to obfuscate my code aswell.

Thanks for reading, hopefully someone with a fresh pair of eyes can take a look and see what I am doing wrong. I am new to using preact and vite so a little help would be appreciated.

Kind regards.

Edit:

Ok so I realized that it only works when I turn off the vite-plugin-javascript-obfuscator. Also there is a differance between when I build with the plugin on vs off.

When off it generates bunch of files named after the files that are getting glob imported, and when the plugin is on these files don't get generated. Is it possible to somehow make it so the glob just puts the code inside the existing bundling of code and then obfuscate it all etc?